# Passing strings in C

Tags: c, string, structure

I'm implementing a rope data structure. How do I pass my string values? They show up as "(null)". I think my char word is not setup properly. I'm new to C, coming from C++. This is eventually to be a text editor, but for now I'm just trying to display inputed strings in an orderly list by index number.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct treeNode
{
    int i, length; 
    char word;
    struct treeNode *left;
    struct treeNode *right;
} treeNode;

treeNode *insert(treeNode *node, int i, char word, int length)
{
    printf("Insert %d :", word);
    if(node==NULL)
    {
        treeNode *temp;
        temp = (treeNode *)malloc(sizeof(treeNode));
        temp->i = i;
        temp->word;
        temp->length;
        temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
        return temp;
    }

    if(i >(node->i))
        node->right = insert(node->right, i, word, length);

    else if(i < (node->i))
        node->left = insert(node->left,i,word,length);
    return node;
}

void PrintInorder(treeNode *node)
{
    if(node==NULL)
        return;
    PrintInorder(node->left);
    printf("%d", node->i);
    printf("%s", node->word);
    PrintInorder(node->right);
}

void main()
{
    treeNode *root = NULL;
    char word[256];
    int length, a;
    for(a = 0; a < 3; a++)
    {
        printf("Enter word: ");
        scanf("%s", word);
        length = strlen(word);      
        root = insert(root, a, *word,length);
    }
    printf("Print in order:\n");  
    PrintInorder(root);
}
```

Comment: `printf("Insert %d :",word );` => `printf("Insert %s \n",word );`

Comment: `char word` is a single character. You should either use `char *word` and do the memory allocation/deallocation yourself or use a `char word[256]` (being optimistic about the max length of word you can expect).

Comment: Use char word[256] With in my insert function and struct?

Comment: BTW, [tag:rope] tag is not for the rope structure, but for a Python library. I suggest [tag:data-structures].

Answer (score 1):

You need `char *word` in your `treeNode` to represent a string (a bit of rope). You need to define `insert` with `char *word`, and call it with `word`, not `*word` (because in the calling context, that will be the first character of `word`). And finally, you actually need some assignment: `temp->word = word`.

There's other logical errors in the code, in particular not handling `i` or `length` in any significant way, but they do not stop you from printing in order, at least.

EDIT:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct treeNode
{
    int i, length; 
    //char word;                // this only stores a single character
    char *word;               // needs to be a pointer so it can point to string
    struct treeNode *left;
    struct treeNode *right;
}treeNode;

// this accepts a single character as `word`, not a string
// treeNode *insert(treeNode *node, int i, char word, int length){
// needs to be `*word`
treeNode *insert(treeNode *node, int i, char *word, int length)
{
    printf("Insert %d :",word );
    if(node==NULL)
    {
        treeNode *temp;
        temp = (treeNode *)malloc(sizeof(treeNode));
        temp->i = i;
        // temp->word;           // This does nothing;
        temp->word = word;    // This assigns the pointer
        temp->length;
        temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
        return temp;
    }

    // This logic does not work correctly... What is `i` specifically?
    if(i >(node->i))
        node->right = insert(node->right,i,word,length); // OK because passing pointer

    else if(i < (node->i))
        node->left = insert(node->left,i,word,length); // OK because passing pointer
    return node;
}

void PrintInorder(treeNode *node)
{
    if(node==NULL)
         return;
    PrintInorder(node->left);
    printf("%d",node->i);
    printf("%s",node->word);
    PrintInorder(node->right);
}

void main()
{
    treeNode *root = NULL;
    char word[256];
    int length, a;
    for(a = 0; a < 3; a++)
    {
        printf("Enter word: ");
        scanf("%s", word);
        length = strlen(word);      
        // root = insert(root, a, *word,length); // This would only pass the first character of `word`
        root = insert(root, a, word,length);  // We want to pass the word pointer
    }
    printf("Print in order:\n");  
    PrintInorder(root);
}
```

Comment: How about insert(root,a,*word,length); ? If I get ride of pointers like said I get rope.c:19:16: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
     temp->word = word;

Comment: You can't get rid of pointers; but you need to differentiate when `*word` means "`word` is a pointer", and when it means "the contents of pointer `word`".

Comment: So it should be a char *word[256]; array of pointers? I dont understand when to distinguish.

Comment: @jab: thank you for editing. Correcting indentation where it is clearly wrong is appreciated, but please be aware that in C the styles of **placement of braces** and **spaces around operators** are highly personal, and so should **not** be adjusted to conform to your, or anyone else but the OP's, taste.

Comment: "int i" was to be an index number for each node that could be retrieved. But since this is a rope, maybe I should be using length as my comparison.

Comment: Forgot to add, when it runs, each word is replaced with the last and it only prints last word.

Comment: Ah yeah, I missed that. You are reusing the same buffer `word[256]`; since you only store the pointer to this place, it will always point to the last word entered. You'd have to allocate separate storage for each word. As for `i`, yes, rope nodes typically only store their length and content.

Comment: So, how could I go about assigning to each word?

Comment: after every input, `malloc` and `strcpy`.

Comment: Ok, so I have         char *word = malloc(sizeof(char)*256);
But what function is using strcpy? Also, thank's a lot for the help.

Comment: No, `char word[256]` is fine. After the user inputs `word`, find the `strlen` of it, `malloc` that much space plus one and assign the pointer to *another* variable (e.g. `char *storedword`), then `strcpy` the `word` into it. This way, when you overwrite `word`, you will still have `storedword` copy.

Comment: I have it in this order `
             scanf("%s", word);
  length = strlen(word);   
        char *word = malloc(sizeof(char)*length+1);
  char *wordcpy = word;
  strcpy (wordcpy,word);
      root = insert(root, a,wordcpy,length);`

Comment: No, that can't work, you're doubly declaring `word` (once as `char word[256]`, and once as `char *word`); and even if you weren't, you are assigning the pointer of the newly `malloc`'d area to `word`, overwriting the previous value, so you don't know where the `scanf`'d string is; your `strcpy` is copying rubbish to itself, as you just said `wordcpy` is the same as `word`. You need to pay attention to what is in each pointer at which time, not to lose anything.

Answer (score 0):

This worked as a solution. Thanks again Amadan

```
int main(){
   treeNode *root = NULL;
   int length, a;
    for(a=0;a<3;a++)
     {
      char *word = malloc(sizeof(char)*length+1); 
      printf("Enter word: ");
      scanf("%s",word);
      length = strlen(word);        
      char *wordcpy = word;
      strcpy (wordcpy,word); 
      root = insert(root, a,wordcpy,length);
     }
PrintInorder(root);
    return 0;
}
```